# SQL Class table inheritance, how to search fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I use Class Table Inheritance http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html
to store different types of products.

I'm wondering the best way to search in these tables.

Supposing all tables names are in the form `'product_%product_type%'` and I want to search the products having a blue color.

The color field might not be present in all tables.

I think about SHOW TABLES LIKE product_%, and then SHOW COLUMNS FROM (result) LIKE 'color' to get all tables having that column, and then do my SELECT from the result of that.

Is there an other solution ? Thanks

Comment: What flavor of sql are you using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 0):

Pull the colour attribute into a ProductColor table.

For your object model mapping think of it as  "Pullover implements ProductColor".